# What interesting uses of MathJax are there, other than mathematical typesetting?

Tags: discussion, mathjax

What interesting uses of MathJax are there, other than [mathematical typesetting](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), that might be useful for Code Review?

Comment: hmm.. this could be interesting as [tag:faq] entry...

Answer (score 8):

You can use it to get color text, such as \$
\bbox[black]{\color{white}{\textrm{white}}}\
\color{black}{\textrm{black}}\ 
\color{red}{\textrm{red}}\ 
\color{green}{\textrm{green}}\ 
\color{blue}{\textrm{blue}}\ 
\color{cyan}{\textrm{cyan}}\ 
\color{magenta}{\textrm{magenta}}\
\bbox[gray]{\color{yellow}{\textrm{yellow}}}
\$.

The MathJax `\color` command works [differently from the \$\LaTeX\$ `\color` command](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-docs/wiki/TeX-and-Colors).  The MathJax syntax is `\color{red}{apple}`; the \$\LaTeX\$ syntax is just `\color{red}`, which changes the color of all subsequent text.

Any standard [CSS color name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value) should work, e.g. \$\color{firebrick}{\texttt{\color{firebrick}{blah}}}\$.

To change the background color, you can use [`\bbox[bgcolorname]{content}`](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#bbox).

Comment: Don't do this, but what some people did on Math.SE a while back was prepend \$\bbox[red]{\color{red}{\boxed{\color{white}{+500}}}}\$ to their title to indicate a promised bounty.

Comment: @anorton I don't believe Code Review allows MathJax in question titles. And if anyone tried to pull something like that, it would get [Jamalized](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1675/9357) away.

Answer (score 8):

You can make tables using `\begin{array}{colspec} … \end{array}`, where `colspec` is some string consisting of `l`, `c`, `r` specifying left, center, and right alignment for the columns.  The `colspec` may also have `|` characters indicating the placement of vertical column-separating bars.

To draw horizontal row-separating lines, use the `\hline` command.

Here is a [moderately complex example](//codereview.stackexchange.com/a/49709/9357):

$$
\newcommand{smallm}[0]{\overset{n\ \gg\ m}{\longrightarrow}}
\begin{array}{|l|c|c|}
                        \hline \\
               & \textrm{Straightforward approach, done well} & \textrm{Fenwick tree} \\
                        \hline \\
\textrm{Space} & O(m + n) \smallm O(n)             & O(m) \smallm O(1) \\
                        \hline \\
\textrm{Time}  & O(m + n) \smallm O(n)             & O((m + n) \log m) \smallm O(n) \\
                        \hline
\end{array}$$

Here is a [very complex example](//codereview.stackexchange.com/a/54047/9357) of a truth table:

$$\begin{array}{ccc|c|c}
\text{*p == *q} & \text{*q != '\0'} & \text{*p != '\0'} & {\begin{array}{l}\text{*p!='\0' &&}\\\text{*q!='\0' &&}\\\text{*p==*q}\end{array}} & \begin{array}{l}\text{*q != '\0' &&}\\\text{*p == *q}\end{array} \\
\hline \\
\begin{array}{c}T\\T\end{array} & \begin{array}{c}T\\T\end{array} & \begin{array}{c}T\\F\end{array} & \begin{array}{c}T\\F\ \textrm{(impossible)}\end{array} &  T \\         
\hline \\
\begin{array}{c}T\\T\end{array} & \begin{array}{c}F\\F\end{array} & \begin{array}{c}T\\F\end{array} & \begin{array}{c}F\ \textrm{(impossible)}\\F\end{array} &  F \\         
\hline \\
\begin{array}{c}F\\F\end{array} & \begin{array}{c}T\\T\end{array} & \begin{array}{c}T\\F\end{array} & \begin{array}{c}F\\F\end{array} &  F \\
\hline \\
\begin{array}{c}F\\F\end{array} & \begin{array}{c}F\\F\end{array} & \begin{array}{c}T\\F\end{array} & \begin{array}{c}F\\F\end{array} &  F \\
\end{array}$$

See the [source](/revisions/a3c821ef-f44a-4e54-a5ca-0d0dad6fa955/view-source) for the examples above, or by right-clicking on each table and selecting *Show Math As → TeX Commands*.

Comment: Since Stack Exchange [now supports Markdown tables](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356997/148099), it is no longer necessary, in most cases, to resort to using MathJax.

Answer (score 8):

You can draw [box-and-pointer diagrams](/a/1829/9357) using a combination of `\fbox{}` and arrows.

$$
\newcommand{ptr}[1]{\overset{\mathtt{#1}}{\longrightarrow}}
\begin{align*}
                                             &\mathtt{newNode} \\
                                             &\quad\downarrow  \\
\mathtt{head} \ptr{} \fbox{first} \ptr{next} &\fbox{another} \ptr{next} \mathtt{null} \\
                                             &\fbox{second}  \ptr{next}
                                              \fbox{rest}    \ptr{next}
                                              \fbox{of}      \ptr{next}
                                              \fbox{list}    \ptr{next} \mathtt{null}
\end{align*}
$$